# ng-repeat + ng-bind Generates 120 loops when should be only 20. No idea why

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Trying to create a dynamic svg icon generator to flesh out a grid of 5 days * 4 time periods per day with a built-on-the-fly svg.

Expected: 20 repeats

Result: 120 repeats, which has 20 svgs that repeat the contents 5 times

Why? No idea.

**somecontroller.js:**

```
var counter = 0; 
$scope.iconGenerator = function ( i, parenti, tod ) {
     counter++; 
     // console.log(counter);
     //append svg contents
 }`
```

**index.html**

```
<div class = "row">
    <div class = "forecast-day col-md-fifth" ng-repeat = 'day in forecastData'>
        <div class = "forecast-group" ng-repeat = "dayDetails in day.conditions">
            <svg id = "{{myID($index, $parent.$index)}}" 
                    ng-bind = "iconGenerator($index,$parent.$index, dayDetails)">
             </svg>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**data.json:**

```
[
    {
        "ID"        : 0,
        "conditions": [
            {
                "key": "value"
            },
            {
                "key": "value"
            },
            {
                "key": "value"
            },
            {
                "key": "value"
            }
        ]
    }
    //array contains total: 5 objects like above
]
```

Comment: Can we see the data for forecastDate?  Maybe a plnkr would help.

Comment: I'm forking off of the plunker that was set up below: http://plnkr.co/edit/eMams7nTe5qcxw2jC39i?p=preview

I've added the $scope to counter so you can see that it outputs hundreds of iterations even though it only shows the 20.

Comment: It seems to be something about using $index and $parent.$index making it run loops within loops ... still unclear but getting there.

Comment: if Your iconGenerator changes data in forecastData, ngRepeat will HAVE TO iterate everything once more to display that content with  those changes. It may end up with loooooot of repeats...

Answer (score 0):

#### Edit:

I get it now. You are incrementing the value of a variable in the function you call in the `ng-bind` directive. This is never a good idea. I think that `ng-bind` must always refer to a variable or a 'getter' function that does not modify the state of the application.

To understand what I am trying to suggest, look again at the plunk  http://plnkr.co/edit/eMams7nTe5qcxw2jC39i?p=preview. I added an input box with an `ng-model`of x. Try modifying the input. Every time you change the input, angularjs has to reload the data in the entire document to check if anything changed. To do this, it must call the function iconGenerator repeatedly. In your case this function increments a value - and as a result the value increases every time you make a change.

You cannot rely on angular calling the iconGenerator function only once. So you need to change the code keeping that in consideration.

---

I tried to recreate your code here : http://plnkr.co/edit/eMams7nTe5qcxw2jC39i?p=preview and it seems to work fine. I think the problem is somewhere else (aside from the code you posted).

```
<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.0" data-semver="1.3.0" src="//code.angularjs.org/1.3.0/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script>
    angular.module('app', [])
      .controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.forecastData = [{
            "ID": 0,
            "conditions": [{
              "key": "value"
            }, {
              "key": "value"
            }, {
              "key": "value"
            }, {
              "key": "value"
            }]
          }, {
            "ID": 1,
            "conditions": [{
              "key": "value"
            }, {
              "key": "value"
            }, {
              "key": "value"
            }, {
              "key": "value"
            }]
          }, {
            "ID": 2,
            "conditions": [{
              "key": "value"
            }, {
              "key": "value"
            }, {
              "key": "value"
            }, {
              "key": "value"
            }]
          }, {
            "ID": 3,
            "conditions": [{
              "key": "value"
            }, {
              "key": "value"
            }, {
              "key": "value"
            }, {
              "key": "value"
            }]
          }, {
            "ID": 4,
            "conditions": [{
              "key": "value"
            }, {
              "key": "value"
            }, {
              "key": "value"
            }, {
              "key": "value"
            }]
          }

        ];
        var counter = 0;
        $scope.iconGenerator = function(i, parenti, tod) {
          counter++;
          //append svg contents
        };
      });
  </script>
</head>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="day in forecastData">
      <div ng-repeat="dayDetails in day.conditions">
        <svg id="{{myID($index, $parent.$index)}}" ng-bind="iconGenerator($index,$parent.$index, dayDetails)">
        </svg>
        {{$parent.$index}}-{{$index}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I'm forking off of the you set up http://plnkr.co/edit/eMams7nTe5qcxw2jC39i?p=preview

I've added the $scope to counter so you can see that it outputs hundreds of iterations even though it only shows the 20.